# While creating div in HTML it is returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below is my HTML Code, the alert Message returns **Undefined** i.e the "div_" is not created.

Please help to resolve this:

```
var piediv = document.createElement('div');
piediv.id = "div_" ;
alert($('#div_').attr('id'));
```

Comment: Use jQuery if you have it `const $pieDiv = $("<div/>",{"id":"div_"}).appendTo("body")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the div as body's child first.

```js
var piediv = document.createElement('div');
piediv.id = "div_" ;
document.body.appendChild(piediv);
alert($('#div_').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that would be a comment and a vote to close, no?

Comment: @mplungjan Since we have less reputation,I would prefer not not close it and upvote for it

Comment: I would prefer `const $pieDiv = $("<div/>",{"id":"div_"}).appendTo("body")` to this mix of jQuery and DOM, and I am not even a purist

Answer (score -2):

You have to set attribute of div  try this 100% worked .

**1st Method** :

```js
var piediv = document.createElement('div');
        piediv.setAttribute("id", "div_");
        $("body").append(piediv);
        alert($('#div_').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2nd Method** as suggested by @mplungjan :

```js
var pieDiv = $("<div/>",{"id":"div_"}).appendTo("body");
           
           alert($('#div_').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code alerts undefined. See other answer why

Comment: Also .id works just as well as setAttribute

Comment: @mplungjan now check it .

Comment: Now it works, I still do not like the mix of DOM and jQuery

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for guide lines and proper way .

Comment: Sure. But I did not suggest you copied my code into your answer

Comment: @mplungjan   yes i have coppied because lots of users are not read the comments so i have added in my answer .  if you want to remove than tell me i will delte my answer .

Comment: @mplungjan thnaks